# Как в GET передать символ "#" ? И другие непечатаемые знаки?

Tags: php, link

Отправляю GET запрос

```
http://my_site.ru/gnk.php?link=https://vk.com/app61#wDe8?utm_source= и т.д.
```

В итоге, получаю $link = https://vk.com/app61

После знака # ничего нет.
А мне в переменной нужна полная строка ссылки, включая пробелы, кирилицу и т.д.
Как победить?

Answer (score 0):

Вот это попробуйте ввести `&#35;` вместо просто `#` или если у Вас Get-запрос, то `%23`.

Comment: ну я же не вручную ссылку ввожу. просто скопировал и вставил в хвост. так задолбаешься каждый символ конвертировать

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов, [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)